# Calculating permanents via Branch and Bound

Tags: algorithms, enumerative-combinatorics, permanent

Permanents can be interpreted as [counting directed cycle covers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)#Cycle_covers) of an asymmetric graph with unit cost edge weights.

That interpretation leads to a branch and bound algorithm for calculating the permanent.

I observed that the execution time depends crucially on the order in which the adjacency lists are encountered during recursion, namely that the algorithm is fastest, if the adjacency lists are encountered according to ascending vertex-degrees and slowest if encountered according to descending vertex-degrees; the times were obtained via the following python program:

```
"""
@author: Manfred Weis

Branch and bound directed cycle covers
"""
import time


T0 = [
{1,2},
{2,3,4},
{3,4,5,6},
{4,5,6,7,8},
{5,6,7,8,9,10},
{6,7,8, 9,10,11,12},
{7,8, 9,10,11,12, 0, 1},
{8, 9,10,11,12, 0, 1, 2, 3},
{ 9,10,11,12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{10,11,12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
{11,12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
{12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10},
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11}    
]

T1 = [
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11},    
{12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10},
{11,12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
{10,11,12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
{ 9,10,11,12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{8, 9,10,11,12, 0, 1, 2, 3},
{7,8, 9,10,11,12, 0, 1},
{6,7,8, 9,10,11,12},
{5,6,7,8,9,10},
{4,5,6,7,8},
{3,4,5,6},
{2,3,4},
{1,2}
]

"""
 r is the row index in the adjacency matrix
 c is the adjacency list of vertex r
"""
def cycle_covers( G, r=0):
    #iterate over the adjacency lists of G
    global seen
    global c
    global perm
    global cover
    global cycle_covers
    for c[r] in G[r]:
        if seen[c[r]]:
            # as cycle covers resemble a permutation we skip vertices that
            # ware previously encountered
            continue
        # attach the newly encountered vertex to the permutation
        cover[r] = c[r]
        seen[c[r]] = True
        if r == len(G)-1:
            # print(cover)
            perm += 1
        else:
            # enter recursion
            cycle_covers(G,r+1)
        seen[c[r]] = False # prepare for the next iteration

n=len(T0)
perm = 0
seen = [False]*n
cover   = [0]*n
c = [0]*n
start = time.time()
cycle_covers(T0)
end = time.time()
print(f'ascending:  {end - start}')
print(f'permanent = {perm}')

perm = 0
seen = [False]*n
cover   = [0]*n
c = [0]*n
start = time.time()
cycle_covers(T1)
end = time.time()
print(f'descending: {end - start}')
print(f'permanent = {perm}')
```

which printed

```
ascending:   26.05
permanent = 2016788
descending: 233.97
permanent = 2016788
```

> **Questions:**
>
> - how does the Branch and Bound calculation of the permanent compare to the calculation via [Ryser's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent#Ryser_formula), i.e. how does the quotient of eexecution times grow as a function of $n$?
> - has the impact of ordering of the adjacency lists on the performance of Branch and Bound "exploration" of directed graphs been noticed before in the sense that it is
>   accounted for as a preprocessing step of combinatorial algorithms?